# Postgresql insert into spatial point with web controls

Tags: postgresql

How can I insert into point in `PostgreSQL` with using web controls values `(textbox,dropdownmenu.selectedvalue etc.)` ?

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "textbox4"
```

and my code is like this:

```c#
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into isletmeler(the_geom,no) values(ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+koordinat+")',2322),Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text));",con);
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error - you need to do to the convert statement what you did to "koordinat" i.e. surround it with "+ and +". However, I strongly urge you to use parameters in your query. https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual

Comment: try `NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into isletmeler(the_geom,no) values(ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+koordinat+")',2322),Convert.ToInt32(" & TextBox4.Text &"));",con);`